# Is there a scriptable way to identify the nth partition of a disk?

Tags: shell-script, partition, partition-table, lsblk

Suppose I have a disk located at `/dev/DISK_NAME`. I'm curious if there is a command to find the `n`th partition of this disk.

It seems like this sort of thing should be possible with `lsblk`. The best I can come up with is:

```
lsblk -nlpo NAME,TYPE /dev/DISK_NAME | awk '/part$/ {print $1}' | grep "[^0-9]n$"
```

Here, the `n` in the last grep represents the partition number in question.

The command above works for the arch linux machine I'm currently on, where `DISK_NAME=sda` and the output of `lsblk -nlpo NAME,TYPE` is

```
/dev/sda  disk
/dev/sda1 part
/dev/sda2 part
/dev/sda3 part
/dev/sda5 part
```

My command also works on my arch linux machine where `DISK_NAME=nvme0n1` and the output of `lsblk -nlpo NAME,TYPE` is

```
/dev/nvme0n1   disk
/dev/nvme0n1p1 part
/dev/nvme0n1p2 part
```

Still, this feels rather hacky, and I'm not sure if it would work on an arbitrary disk.

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: On what OS? Also, that... doesn't actually work. You seem to be expecting to find non-numeric characters and then an `n` before the end of the line. What output are you expecting? Also, what is the Nth partition? Should extended partitions count? If so, the Nth partition of sdX will always be sdXN so I don't quite see what you would need to script.

Comment: I'm on arch linux. I ran into this problem because I had a script that assumed the Nth partition of `/dev/DISK_NAME` was `/dev/DISK_NAMEN` that failed when `DISK_NAME=nvme0`. In this case, the Nth partition was `/dev/nvme0pN`.

Comment: So it sounds like my problem is that I'm ignorant of the ways disks are generally partitioned. I assumed that each partition of a disk is tagged with a number that I'm clumsily calling the "Nth partition"

Comment: Not sure if you're ignorant or if I am, but I'm pretty sure one or both of us is, yes :) You're quite right about the weird `/dev/nvme0pN` names, I've seen those but don't remember under what circumstances. I believe those are the special flash type drives some laptops have for the OS. It would probably help if you could edit and show us the output of `lsblk -nlpo NAME,TYPE /dev/nvme`. However, even in that case, why would you have the letter `n` after the number? Wouldn't the 2nd partition be `nvme0p2`?

Comment: @terdon the letter n comes after `[^0-9]`, which should match any *non-integer* character (because of the `^` symbol).

Comment: Yes, but but you are looking for a lower case `n` for some reason. Isn't the partition naming scheme `nvme`, then the disk number, then `p` and then the partition number? Like `nvme0p1`? (also see [persistent device naming for NVMe storage devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452135))

Comment: @terdon I meant for `n` to algebraically represent the partition number in question. So replace `n` with `1` for `nvme0p1`

Comment: NVMe disks typically have a namespace ID after the NVME controller number, i.e. `/dev/nvme0` = first NVMe controller, `/dev/nvme0n1` = its first (and often only) namespace (whole "disk"), and `/dev/nvme0n1p1` = first partition of first namespace of first NVMe controller. Consumer NVMe stuff typically supports just one namespace, while enterprise-grade NVMe might support more than one. If Arch has decided to hide the namespace ID, that's a new thing and probably Arch's own idea.

Comment: One question to make this more complicated: With `n = 1` do you want partition number 1 or first partition on the disk? Because strictly speaking `sda1` is not guaranteed to be first partition on `sda`.

Comment: @telcoM My mistake. On my arch system its `DISK_NAME=nvme0n1` (I forgot the `n1` when typing from my memory).

Comment: @VojtechTrefny Yeah that's what I thought. So what's the best way to determine what the "nth partition on the disk" is?

Comment: This sounds like the xy problem

Comment: @symcbean No it is not. I want to know the name of the nth partition on my disk.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `sda1` exists at all - I have a SSD with only sda4 and sda5. So would the first partition be the one with the lowest start LBA?

Or perhaps the first entry in the partition table? According to `parted -l`,

```
...
Number  Start  End    Size    File system  Name                   Flags
 2      316MB  333GB  333GB   ext4         /mnt/backup
 3      333GB  791GB  457GB   ext4         /mnt/filestore
 4      791GB  832GB  41.9GB  ext4         /run/timeshift/backup
 1      832GB  841GB  8590MB  ext4         /mnt/music
```

Which is the first partition - is it **2** (which has the lowest LBA) or is it **1** (which has the lowest partition number).

If you prefer the ancient `fdisk -l` command, then this will sort the partition table for you [so that lowest numbered partitions come first].

Comment: A minor note for the sake of completeness: after you get the type of partition list you want, filter out any headings and other non-partition lines, and then you can use the old `... | head -$n | tail -1` trick to pick the nth line (`$n` is assumed to contain the number of the desired line).

Comment: Yes, I realize now that I was making assumptions that the names of the partitions were indicative of the location on the disk which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Now that I've read this answer and the comments, I've realized that my question should have  been "how can I identify the name of the partition of `DISK_NAME` with the lowest LBA"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsblk` JSON ouput and `jq` tool for the purpose, it looks less hacky IMHO:

```
lsblk -J ${disk} | jq ".blockdevices[0].children[${partiton_number}].name"
```